# AngularJs: why doesn't ng-switch update when I use ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I tried using `ng-click` to update the variable used in `ng-switch`, but `ng-switch` doesn't seem to have picked up the change. See the example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jx8DNlrJDuaUBKVwZQtQ

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running into scope inheritance issues. See: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Fixed version: http://plnkr.co/edit/ENm5HBYno8yHblLlE8CA?p=preview

Comment: Interesting, so if I understand correctly, ng-switch creates a new scope and a new 'edit' variable which is changed in ng-click, but not the old 'edit' that ng-switch is watching on. But why does your solution fix it? Why doesn't it just create another 'x.edit'?

Comment: Because of the way prototypal inheritance works. When you were setting the edit property, it was being attached to the current (i.e. ngSwitch-created) scope, and the parent scope (yours) didn't know about it. By putting a property in-between the edit variable and the scope (i.e. x.edit), you force it to look for the x first, which it finds on the correct scope, and then set the edit property.

Answer (score 0):

You just weren't toggling.  Try this.

```
<div ng-switch on="edit">
  <div ng-switch-when=true>
    <a ng-click="edit=!edit">Cancel {{edit}}</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when=false>
    <a ng-click="edit=!edit">Edit {{edit}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did this not work for you?  I tested it and it worked for me.  Did I misunderstand your question?