# How can I make my Ionic Button refresh all ion-views. (Preferable in most just revaluate a ng-switch)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

in my view I have a `ng-switch` like:

```
<div ng-switch on="team.isFavorite">
    <button class="button button-energized snbutton" ng-switch-when="false" ng-click="makeTeamFavorite()">
      Show team on dashboard
    </button>
    <p class="snmsg" ng-switch-default>
      This team is shown on the dashboard
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I make my Ionic Button refresh all ion-views.
*Preferable* in most just reevaluate a `ng-switch`, in 1 reload EVERYTHING)

### What I tried in my controller:

```
.controller('List-PeopleCtrl', function($ionicHistory, $state, $scope, $stateParams, Teams) {
  $scope.makeTeamFavorite = function() {
      Teams.setFavoriteId($stateParams.teamId);
      $ionicHistory.clearCache();
      $state.go($state.current);
  }
  $scope.team = Teams.get($stateParams.teamId);
  $scope.team.isFavorite = Teams.getFavoriteId()==$stateParams.teamId;
  $scope.people = Teams.members($stateParams.teamId);
})
```

it would invalidate all caches I guess but it didn't work anyway :D

### Note

- I searched but didn't find anything to do this..
- I don't want to mark my ion view with `cache=false` and opt out of all caching
- I *think* this is  ionic specific but it could be my general lack of knowledge concerning AngularJS :D
- **the point is it works (without clearing the cache) when I next open the view again .. just that it isn't reloaded while looking at it**

EDIT:
I also tried with:

```
      $ionicHistory.clearCache();
      $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
```

or just

```
      $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
```

NO LUCK

Comment: What's $ionicHistory? It's not clear what you are trying to do here

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/

Comment: I think this question is quite ionic specific but it could be my general lack of knowledge concerning angularjs :D

Comment: I don't know ionic sorry

Comment: Did you mean to use `$ionicHistory.clearCache();` ? If you don't have `()` the method doesn't actually get called.

Comment: yes, sorry typo. .. the point is it works when I next open the view again .. just that it isn't reloaded while looking at it

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20587934/3052648

Comment: I think you need to disable a cache for those paricular state by mention `cache: false` on state level. take look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932268/2435473

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't seem to be ionic specific nor `ng-switch` specific, but *seems* to be `ui-router` specific. If I understand correctly, you want to refresh your view when you click your button and execute some data logic on `Teams`. I see this here

```
$state.go($state.current);
```

However, this simply won't do it for you because since your path has not changed your controller will not re-run. However, `$state.go()` offers additional parameters, including one we need for just this - `reload`. Try the following...

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true }); //second parameter is for $stateParams
```

This will refresh your views and re-run your controller, so you'll see this reflected in the UI. See [$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) docs for more information

---

Furthermore, if you and others would like to see this in action I have crafted two simplistic examples. The code here is by no means best-practice driven, but is indeed self-descriptive enough to demonstrate the core issue and solution.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/99gxagoz/) - working - using `$state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });`

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mahs1a0v/) - not working - using only `$state.go($state.current);`

Comment: Thanks! Ill try this out tomorrow but what you say sounds quite reasonable!

Comment: @Daij-Djan sure let me know how it goes! Please share feedback for your findings and I'll try to help further if needed

Comment: also with that (which sounds reasonable) my controller isn't rerun :( I debugged the code and $state looks valid and there are no JS errors thrown

Comment: @Daij-Djan your controller should definitely be re-run. Put a `console.log()` at the top of your controller and it'll log out a message when you `$state.go` with the `reload: true` paramater

Comment: @Daij-Djan can you craft a plunker for this by chance?

Comment: @Daij-Djan another question for you, is `Teams.setFavoriteId` asynchronous?

Comment: @Daij-Djan any new progress on this by any chance?

Comment: @Daij-Djan I am curious if you made any progress on this. Can you share some progress details? I see the bounty period expired but I a still interested in helping you

Comment: @Daij-Djan it't been a while - do you have any interesting updates on this? Can you please accept this answer if you found helpful?