# Understanding ng-scope inheritance/hierarchy

Tags: angularjs

Just want to understand more about ng-scope inheritance/hierarchy, because i don't exactly understand how it works.

Assume i have a block like this

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlName">
<div ng-scope-1>
    <div ng-scope-2>
        <div ng-scope-3>
            <div ng-scope-4></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it correct to assume that from controller's point, to get to

- Scope 1, i need to define $scope.scope1 in the controller
- Scope 2, i need to define $scope.scope1.scope2 in the controller?
- Scope 4, i need to define $scope.scope1.scope2.scope3.scope4 in the controller?

And what if scope 3 block is appended to scope 2 using ngInclude? Does the scope referring changes too?

I asked this because of this one question here - [AngularJs: why doesn't ng-switch update when I use ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587893/angularjs-why-doesnt-ng-switch-update-when-i-use-ng-click)

And the solution seems to mention about scope inheritance. Not sure if the example i gave above is related to the scope inheritance too.

Comment: Do you understand well prototypical inheritance? Scope one is based on prototypes.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies